# Redrawing part of canvas vs layers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Let's say I have a canvas. The top half is animated constantly, while the bottom half is rarely ever changed. In my scenario, I have many different things animated/not animated so I would not like to have that many canvases on top of each other.

The current way I go about this is drawing animations on the whole page, then drawing the bottom half on top of it.
Would it optimize speeds if I were to only draw on the top half, and never redraw the bottom half? Or does it not matter?

Thanks, I appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 3):

Canvas performance is usually related to how many pixels you change. So only drawing half the canvas, *without clearing the canvas*, will generally be faster than updating the entire canvas. When you're not drawing to a canvas it will also note consume any CPU resources because it essentially acts as an image.

However, as is the case with all performance-related questions, don't look for advice, **do some measurements**!

Use the built in developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) to profile the rendering performance. Enable screen redraw rectangles to see what parts of the browser are redrawing. See if only drawing on one part of the canvas causes the browser to redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know I can do that in developer tools.

Comment: Every single performance metric can be monitored in the developer tools. From function calls, memory usage and CPU, all the way to redraw times per frame in milliseconds.